# JMS connection handshake is failing for SSLCipherSuite SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I am using Spring boot 1.5.2 and Java 8, here is how I am creating connection factory object,

```
private MQQueueConnectionFactory ibmMQConnectionFactory() {
      MQQueueConnectionFactory ibmMQConnectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
    try {
        ibmMQConnectionFactory.setHostName(ibmMQHostName);
        ibmMQConnectionFactory.setPort(ibmMQPort);
        ibmMQConnectionFactory.setChannel(ibmMQChannel);
        ibmMQConnectionFactory.setQueueManager(ibmMQQueueManager);
        ibmMQConnectionFactory.setTransportType(ibmMQTransportType);
        ibmMQConnectionFactory.setSSLCipherSuite(ibmSslCipher);

    } catch (JMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        LOGGER.error("ibmMQConnectionFactory() - Exception occurred: ", e);
    } 
    return ibmMQConnectionFactory;
}
```

If I do not use cipher suite “SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA” on client side I get this error,

```
2017-03-27 13:08:30.030 ERROR 12700 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].  
[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in   
context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested
exception is org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized
exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to
queue manager 'XXXX' with connection mode 'Client' and host name
'xxx.xxx.com(xxxxx)'.
Check the queue manager is started and if running in client mode, check there
is a listener running. Please see the linked exception for more information.;
nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call    
failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2397' ('MQRC_JSSE_ERROR').]   
with root cause
com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2397;AMQ9641: Remote CipherSpec error  
for channel 'CLIENT.xxxx' to host ''. [3=CLIENT.xxxx] at     com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.analyseErrorSegment(RemoteConnection.java:3850) ~[jmqi-7.1.0.7.jar:7.1.0.7 - k710-007-151026]
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.receiveTSH(RemoteConnection.java:2749) ~[jmqi-7.1.0.7.jar:7.1.0.7 - k710-007-151026]
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.initSess(RemoteConnection.java:1024) ~[jmqi-7.1.0.7.jar:7.1.0.7 - k710-007-151026]
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.connect(RemoteConnection.java:717) ~[jmqi-7.1.0.7.jar:7.1.0.7 - k710-007-151026]
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getSessionFromNewConnection(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:356) ~[jmqi-7.1.0.7.jar:7.1.0.7 - k710-007-151026]
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getSession(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:265) ~[jmqi-7.1.0.7.jar:7.1.0.7 - k710-007-151026]
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionPool.getSession(RemoteConnectionPool.java:144) ~[jmqi-7.1.0.7.jar:7.1.0.7 - k710-007-151026]
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1709) ~[jmqi-7.1.0.7.jar:7.1.0.7 - k710-007-151026]
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1347) ~[jmqi-7.1.0.7.jar:7.1.0.7 - k710-007-151026]
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.<init>(WMQConnection.java:350) ~[mqjms-7.1.0.7.jar:7.1.0.7 - k710-007-151026]
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:6789) ~[mqjms-7.1.0.7.jar:7.1.0.7 - k710-007-151026]
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:6157) ~[mqjms-7.1.0.7.jar:7.1.0.7 - k710-007-151026]
at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:285) ~[mqjms-7.1.0.7.jar:7.1.0.7 - k710-007-151026]
at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createCommonConnection(MQConnectionFactory.java:6126) ~[mqjms-7.1.0.7.jar:7.1.0.7 - k710-007-151026]
at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:115) ~[mqjms-7.1.0.7.jar:7.1.0.7 - k710-007-151026]
at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.createConnection(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:198) ~[mqjms-7.1.0.7.jar:7.1.0.7 - k710-007-151026]
at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:180) ~[spring-jms-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:474) ~[spring-jms-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:570) ~[spring-jms-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.convertAndSend(JmsTemplate.java:658) ~[spring-jms-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at com.xxx.messaging.client.JmsClientImplMemoPadER.send(JmsClientImplMemoPadER.java:49) ~[classes/:na]
at com.xxx.messaging.controller.MessageController.sendMemoPad(MessageController.java:65) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_121]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_121]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
```

According to IBM documentation its solution is “Ensure that there is a cipher suite set on the client matching the cipher spec on the queue manager's server connection channel.”
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21614686

When I set cipher suite “SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA” on client machine to match the cipher spec of queue manager “TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA”, I get this error,

```
ERROR 8424 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    :         
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] 
threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception
occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is    
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to
queue manager 'XXXXX' with connection mode 'Client' and host name   
'XXX.XXXXX.com(1XXXX)'.
Check the queue manager is started and if running in client mode, check there  
is a listener running. Please see the linked exception for more information.;
nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call 
failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2393'
('MQRC_SSL_INITIALIZATION_ERROR').] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported ciphersuite   
SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite.valueOf(CipherSuite.java:228) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuiteList.<init>(CipherSuiteList.java:79) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.setEnabledCipherSuites(SSLSocketImpl.java:2461) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.makeSocketSecure(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1994) ~[jmqi-7.1.0.7.jar:7.1.0.7 - k710-007-151026]
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.connnectUsingLocalAddress(RemoteTCPConnection.java:855) ~[jmqi-7.1.0.7.jar:7.1.0.7 - k710-007-151026]
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.protocolConnect(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1262) ~[jmqi-7.1.0.7.jar:7.1.0.7 - k710-007-151026]
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.connect(RemoteConnection.java:714) ~[jmqi-7.1.0.7.jar:7.1.0.7 - k710-007-151026]
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getSessionFromNewConnection(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:356) ~[jmqi-7.1.0.7.jar:7.1.0.7 - k710-007-151026]
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getSession(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:265) ~[jmqi-7.1.0.7.jar:7.1.0.7 - k710-007-151026]
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionPool.getSession(RemoteConnectionPool.java:144) ~[jmqi-7.1.0.7.jar:7.1.0.7 - k710-007-151026]
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1709) ~[jmqi-7.1.0.7.jar:7.1.0.7 - k710-007-151026]
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1347) ~[jmqi-7.1.0.7.jar:7.1.0.7 - k710-007-151026]
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.<init>(WMQConnection.java:350) ~[mqjms-7.1.0.7.jar:7.1.0.7 - k710-007-151026]
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:6789) ~[mqjms-7.1.0.7.jar:7.1.0.7 - k710-007-151026]
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:6157) ~[mqjms-7.1.0.7.jar:7.1.0.7 - k710-007-151026]
at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:285) ~[mqjms-7.1.0.7.jar:7.1.0.7 - k710-007-151026]
at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createCommonConnection(MQConnectionFactory.java:6126) ~[mqjms-7.1.0.7.jar:7.1.0.7 - k710-007-151026]
at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:115) ~[mqjms-7.1.0.7.jar:7.1.0.7 - k710-007-151026]
at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.createConnection(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:198) ~[mqjms-7.1.0.7.jar:7.1.0.7 - k710-007-151026]
at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:180) ~[spring-jms-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:474) ~[spring-jms-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:570) ~[spring-jms-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.convertAndSend(JmsTemplate.java:658) ~[spring-jms-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at com.xxx.messaging.client.JmsClientImplMemoPadER.send(JmsClientImplMemoPadER.java:49) ~[classes/:na]
at com.xxx.messaging.controller.MessageController.sendMemoPad(MessageController.java:65) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_121]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_121]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
```

Comment: ? You have SSL... not TLS...

Comment: I dont see setting TLS option for MQConnectionFactory object. I guess on client I need to specify ssl cipher spec, 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.0.1/com.ibm.mq.csqzaw.doc/ja34740_.htm#ja34740___ja34740_2

Comment: I don't see that as an available suite [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html) - perhaps you have to get it from IBM?

Comment: @GaryRussell I also tried with IBM SDK ibm_sdk80 https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/eclipse/index.html following thread https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/178651/what-tls-ciphersuites-are-supported-when-connectin/ but it did not work. I updated my question with recent details and exception message I am getting on stackoverflow,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43075131/com-ibm-msg-client-jms-detailedjmsexception-jmswmq0018-failed-to-connect-to-qu

Comment: fixed this after using ibm jdk.

Comment: working ok with oracle java 8 using cipher suite TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, ref: www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IV66840

Comment: Hi Ishtiaq, may I know did you specified the cert path for this? If yes, how to do that?

Comment: @phony yes I did, this problem has been fixed now. I used java keytool import https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-3503/ggfen/index.html

Comment: You should write up a answer to your own question to benefit other people that have a similar issue.

Comment: @JoshMc I get message "You can only post once every 3 minutes" when I try to post my answer.

Comment: I had a similar issue in the past, I used the "Contact Us" link at the bottom of the page to send a message to Stackoverflow support, the issue was the result of many connections from our companies HTTP proxy, SO added our IPs to a "whitelist" of some sort to prevent it from happening in the future.

Comment: Thanks @JoshMc. I added my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this after importing certificate using java keytool https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-3503/ggfen/index.html. Also download 
 Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files 8 http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html and replace with your local JRE security jars