# com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'xxx' with connection mode 'yyy' and host name 'zzz'

Tags: ssl, connection, jms, ibm-mq, mq

JMS app requires seven parameters to make successful SSL connection with MQ series given here, 
https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-tls-ssl-wizard/blob/master/com.ibm.mq.ssl-wizard/src/tlswizard/samples/SSLSampleJMS.java

I am trying to interpret these parameters,

1. Conname- the connection name of the server queue manager in the same format as the CONNAME parameter on the MQSC DEFINE CHANNEL command, but without the port specified.

   - I guess this is host name
2. Port - the connection port of the server queue manager.

   - This is port number
3. SvrconnChannelName - the name of the server connection channel on the server queue manager with which the sample program will try to connect.
4. QMgrName - the name of the server queue manager.
5. SSLCiph - the SSL CipherSpec.

   - I am using SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA.
6. SSLKeyr - the name of a single store, which is both the keystore and truststore.
   I generated myjksfile.jks using mycertfile.cert using mypassword with below command and provided path of this file in program as "C:\Users\abc\myjksfile.jks",

   - keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore myjksfile.jks -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias ibmWebSphereMQUTQX -file C:\mqlib\mycertfile.cert
7. SSLKeyrPassword - the SSL key repository password
   the password which I used to generate myjksfile.jks file

Running above program with these seven parameters results this exception,

```
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to     
queue manager 'XXXX' with connection mode 'Client' and host name   
'xxxx.yyyyyy.com(XXXXX)'.Check the queue manager is started and if running in
client mode, check there is a listener running. Please see the linked  
exception for more information. at  
com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException
(Reason.java:580) at  
com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException
(Reason.java:216) at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.<init> 
(WMQConnection.java:431) at  
com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.
createV7ProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:6789) at  
com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.
createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:6157)
at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.
createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:285)
at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createCommonConnection
(MQConnectionFactory.java:6126) at      
com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection 
(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:115) at  
SSLSampleJMS.runSample(SSLSampleJMS.java:176)
at SSLSampleJMS.main(SSLSampleJMS.java:135)
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with
compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2393' ('MQRC_SSL_INITIALIZATION_ERROR').
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException
(Reason.java:204)... 8 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2393;AMQ9204: Connection to
host 'xxxx.yyyyyy.com(XXXXX)' rejected.
[1=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException[CC=2;RC=2393;AMQ9771: SSL handshake failed.
[1=java.lang.IllegalArgumentException[Cannot support
SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA with currently installed   
providers],3=xxxx.yyyyyy.com/XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXXX (xxxx.yyyyyy.com),4=SSLSocket.createSocket,5=default]],3=xxxx.yyyyyy.com(XXXXX),5=RemoteTCPConnection.makeSocketSecure]
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:2098)
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1347)
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.<init>(WMQConnection.java:350)
... 7 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2393;AMQ9771: SSL handshake
failed. [1=java.lang.IllegalArgumentException[Cannot support
SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA with currently installed   
providers],3=xxxx.yyyyyy.com/XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXXX
(xxxx.yyyyyy.com),4=SSLSocket.createSocket,5=default]
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.makeSocketSecure
(RemoteTCPConnection.java:2001) at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.
RemoteTCPConnection.connnectUsingLocalAddress(RemoteTCPConnection.java:855)
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.protocolConnect
(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1262) at 
com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.connect
(RemoteConnection.java:714) at  
com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.
getSessionFromNewConnection(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:356)
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.
getSession(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:265)
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionPool.
getSession(RemoteConnectionPool.java:144)
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1709)
... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot support
SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA with currently installed providers
at com.ibm.jsse2.o.<init>(o.java:29)
at com.ibm.jsse2.as.setEnabledCipherSuites(as.java:5)
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.makeSocketSecure
(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1994)
... 16 more
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: What error is seen on the queue manager in the AMQERR01.LOG at the same time you get the error from SSLSampleJMS.java?

Comment: What version of MQ client and java are you using? Try reading this discussion: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/178651/what-tls-ciphersuites-are-supported-when-connectin.html in particular try adding the following as a command line argument: -Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false

Comment: @JoshMc Nothing displayed in the error log at the same time I get the error from SSLSampleJMS.java. Looks like this occurred before any communication with queue manager and error log did not hold any information of that. Ref: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/291714/after-upgrading-websphere-application-server-was-t.html

Comment: @AdamSmith I am using java 8 and MQ 7.0. After adding -Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false to VM. I am getting com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'XXXX' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'null'.
Check the queue manager is started and if running in client mode, check there is a listener running. Please see the linked exception for more information.
 at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:580)
...

Comment: That's different to your last error right? Now it seems you need to set the host name somewhere?

Comment: I fixed by after using IBM Jdk as oracle Jdk 1.8 was not supporting SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA cipher suites. I still would like to use oracle jdk but when I replace it security jars with ibm security jars I get java.lang.SecurityException: The jurisdiction policy files are not signed by a trusted signer!

Comment: working ok with oracle java 8 using cipher suite TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, ref: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IV66840

Comment: Please post an answer to your own question to benefit people in the future which have the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

Above exception was cause of using wrong cipher suite on JMS clint side. I was using SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA cipher suite on client side and was getting "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException[Cannot support
SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA with currently installed
providers." Using correct cipher suite (TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA) at JMS client side made handshake successful between JMS client and MQ series.
Ref: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IV66840